# Проверить состояние объекстов в листе через Linq запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Добрый день, у меня есть лист с некими объектами у которых есть bool поле isAlive.

Можно ли с помощью одного Linq запроса посмотреть значения у всех объектов?

Например, проверить все ли объекты "мертвы"/"Живы" :

```
bool isAllAlive = list.// Linq запрос.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда ничего не помогает - прочтите уже наконец-то [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)!

В данном случае, вам пригодятся методы [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool isAllAlive = list.All(x => x.IsAlive);
```